# Marketing Cloud - Name of Created Date table

Tags: query, marketing-cloud

I am trying to run a query to find all subscribers for a specific date range and need to work from the Created Date.  I have tried every combination of "Created Date" that makes sense, but none validate - I keep getting an error: "The query syntax is invalid    Invalid column name 'DateCreated'."

What is the correct column name for Created Date?

Thank you -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Created Date` column in the [_Subscribers System Data View](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/).

Perhaps you mean `DateJoined`?

```
select
s.emailaddress
, s.subscriberkey
, s.status
, s.datejoined
from _subscribers s
where s.dateJoined >= dateadd(d,-1, cast(getDate() as date))
```

Reference: [Query Activity (System Data Views)](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

Comment: Yes, that is probably it.  I was looking in the account records and the column name there is Created Date.  The rest of the field labels are fairly consistent, so I knew this had to be different if the other options weren't working.  Thanks!