# Find contacts that were created in the past 6 months?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, contactbuilder

Our client's SFMC Contacts count is overage, and before we can perform the contact deletion to reduce the contacts count, we would like to know the contacts count trend over the past 6 months.

I wonder if we have any approaches to find out that.

My very rough idea is using the [Mobile filter list workaround](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/285259/83900) to get all subscriber keys in All contacts list, then mapping with `_Subscribers` , `_MobileAddress`, and `_PushAddress` data views to get the CreatedDate field then use it to filter out. However MC contact data model is complex with many layers and not all data views using subscriber key but contact ID for mapping so I am not sure how this idea is going to work.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132333/marketing-cloud-name-of-created-date-table ... hope this helps.... you can use `DateJoined` field for `_Subscribers` ..... and `_CreatedDate` field for `_mobileaddress`...  I have no idea on `_PushAddress` lets see what SFMC experts are about to say on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to know your *contacts count trend over the past 6 months*, you can simply run the [Contacts Count report](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_contacts_counts.htm&type=5) in your ENT Business Unit:

[image]

Where you should select a custom date range to cover 6 months:

[image]

It will display the billable contact count by week, and additionally break it down by the contact source, e.g. MobileConnect:

[image]